# Sql Agent, where is the one-time schedule saved when it has been executed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

Schedules in sql agent are set in a sysschedules table:

```
select * from sysschedules
```

Does anyone know, on which information sqlAgent bases on where determining
to execute task or not (of type: one-time)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Microsoft documentation on [dbo.sysschedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx) to provide a robust understanding of the table and its properties.

I think you are looking for the freq_type field.  A value of 1 identifies a schedule as one-time-only.

Please note that I urge caution if you are considering an update against these tables.  It is far better to use the visual components in Sequel Server Management Studio or using the stored procedure sp_update_schedule.  These will handle any extra 'under the hood' operations that generally need to accompany such updates.

GL, I hope this helps.